# EE2 - plugins page blank

Tags: ee2, control-panel, plugin, white-screen-of-death

I’m getting the “white screen of death” in the control panel, though only on the Add-ons->Plugins page.

I have turned on debugging mode, and the issue does not appear to have been caused by a PHP error. Can anyone think of any other reason why an individual control panel page would stop loading? I am getting no errors in the console, and the html is empty.

Many thanks in advance for any help, EE version 2.7.3

Answer (score 2):

EE has to look at all your plugin files to create the list of plugins. You have a rogue plugin that isn't formatted correctly, and is causing the issue.

Start by removing all of your plugins. Then add them back one by one until you find the culprit. You should do this on a staging or development server, of course.